# Anonymous function error in html file while working on extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

The html file keeps giving me an error when I pack the extension.  It says there is a "anonymous function"  I think it might have something to do with the javascript file, but I'm not entirely sure.  Could someone explain this to me and help me fix it? Thanks!

```
index.html:12 (anonymous function) //error

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background-color: aqua; border-style: groove; border-width: 5px; border-color: blue;">
        <h2 style="text-align: center;" id="calculatedText">Answer: </h2>
        <input style="background-color: #30D5C8;" placeholder= "2+2" id="inputBox">
        <button id="calcButton" onclick="calc()" style="background-color: #0FA3C1; ">Click to calculate</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried many different things, such as switching the hex code to a value like aqua or something like that.  Nothing worked or I wouldn't be asking this question!
Thanks for helping!

Comment: You should post your script.js and manifest.json.

Comment: More likely to be something to do with the `calc()` function attached to your button. Is that function defined in your script.js?

Comment: 1) Remove `onclick="calc()"` from html, 2) Add `defer` to `<script` tag in case you don't use DOMContentLoaded event inside script.js, 3) Use addEventListener in script.js to add a listener for `click` event on the button element.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more @wOxxOm also, I have to add quite a few more buttons, so could you explain steps 2 and 3 more

Comment: This is standard JavaScript DOM, see any tutorial on using addEventListener and querySelector.